# How to restrict dropdown select option for that particular row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using `nuxt.js` to develop a web application ,in that i have on page that page responsible for the `custom forms` ,please refer the following image

[image]

In this  page if i click on increment decrement buttons it will create another row upto this part it's working fine,now if i select any **column dropdown** in first row it's selecting but it's automatically updating all rows **column dropdown** ,can you please help me to fix this issue ..?

```html
<template>
  <div class="pt-5 table-responsive">
    <h3>Conditions</h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Column</th>
          <th scope="col">Condition</th>
          <th scope="col">Input Field</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-right">Add/Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
          <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
          <td>
            <select v-model="fields" class="form-select form-control">
              <option
                v-for="conditionField in conditionFields"
                :key="conditionField.id"
              >
                {{ conditionField.name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select v-model="condFies" class="form-select form-control">
              <option
                v-for="typeCondition in typeConditions"
                :key="typeCondition.id"
              >
                {{ typeCondition.name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <base-input placeholder="Type here"></base-input>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <base-button type="secondary" @click="addRow(input)"
              ><i class="ni ni-fat-add"></i>
            </base-button>
            <base-button type="secondary" @click="removeRow(index, input)"
              ><i class="ni ni-fat-delete"></i>
            </base-button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{}],
      fieldInputs: [{}],
      conditions: [],
      forms: [],
      selectedForm: [],
      loadedForm: [],
      conditionFields: [],
      selectFields: [],
      condFies: [],
      fields: [],
      selFields: [],
      report: [],
      typeConditions: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getQueryConditions() {
      try {
        const axios = this.$axios.create()

        axios
          .get(
            'queryconditions'
            // , {
            //     transformRequest: (headers) => {
            //         delete headers.common['Organization-Id'];
            //     }
            // }
          )
          .then((response) => {
            this.conditions = response.data.data
            this.conditions.forEach((element) => {
              if (element.type.includes('condition')) {
                console.log(element)
                this.typeConditions = this.conditions
              }
            })
          })
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of using a single variable `typeConditions` for all rows you need to create an individual copy for each row and customize it

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for answering but it's not possible for to apply variable for every because it's a customisable table so we have have as much row as we want if we increment the row

Comment: Just use an array and add an element to the array when a new row is added. This is easily possible. Or move the row into a subcomponent with its own state.

Comment: I have formatted your question into something more readable.